# Issue with multiline textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I have three text boxes in my webpage (c#). One of them is a multiline textbox.
After running the application, when I press tab the text in the single line textbox is highlighting but not the text in the multiline textbox.

How do I make it so the text in the multiline textbox highlights when I press tab in the browser?

Comment: What browser have you tested, behaves the same in all? You don't want the caret  at the end of the text but highlight all text(so that someone can delete all with one key)?

Answer (score 5):

The Multiline Textbox doesn't support this feature. but if you want to select this text then please go with the following code.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txt" runat="server" TextMode ="MultiLine"  Rows="3" onfocus="this.select();" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to add the `tabindex` attribute to the input field? e.g

```
tabindex="3"
```

Here's an example of this: http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/_INPUT_TABINDEX.html